# What are the make/build/install commands for module?

Tags: compiling, source

I'm working on a hardware issue. In a nutshell, Bluetooth isn't working. Solution I saw was to build and install this package but it's been years since I did that. Could use some hints.

`bcmwl-kernel-source` (Broadcom 802.11 Linux STA wireless driver source)

I'm on this kernel / platform :

```
3.13.0-49-generic #83-Ubuntu SMP Fri Apr 10 20:11:33 UTC 2015 x86_64 86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Chipset is Broadcom BCM4352

Supposition: If this doesn't work, in theory I can just force a re-install of 3.13.0-49-generic to be rid of the twiddling I've done. Verify?

If I'm using the right commands, then this would seem to suggest that the module is not loading... assuming I am looking for the right keywords.

```
user@machine:~$ lsmod | egrep "bcm|4352"
user@machine:~$
```

Answer (score 0):

That uses dkms. Sources of the kernel module are in the bcmwl-kernel-source deb package. They are compiled to get kernel module (*.ko file) when the bcmwl-kernel-source package is installed or the kernel package is upgraded.

So, it doesn't affect the system too much: just an additional kernel module.

Comment: Hint: The last time I built a kernel was before dkms. ;-) Proceedure?

Comment: ...or do you mean that it's automatic? I hope not, because that would mean I still have an issue.

Comment: Automatic. deb gives sources to dkms on installation and deletes kernel module and sources from dkms on deinstallation. What issue? Kernel modules are separate from the kernel.

Comment: This was meant to fix my bluetooth. That was the issue.

Comment: Ok, then the last thing before the driver debugging is checking if the module actually loads.